# Gradle Zip Task: Replace Entire File Content While Being Copied

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I currently have a set of files that contain a DSL that needs to be parsed and converted to XML before being copied over to the destination build directory.

I'm using the eachFile hook to accomplish this, but when I replace the content of the file the source file is being changed as well:

```
task build(type: Zip) {
  with {
    archiveName = "${project.name}-${project.version}.${extension}"
    destinationDir = buildDir
  }

  from('workflow/dsl') {
    eachFile { fileDetails ->
      String xml = new OozieDslParser().parse(fileDetails.getFile())
      fileDetails.setName(fileDetails.getName().replaceFirst(~/\.[^\.]+$/, '.xml')
      fileDetails.getFile().text = xml //This changes the source file as well.
    }
  }

  from('workflow/resources')
}
```

What is the best way to approach this problem?

Unfortunately, the 'expand' and 'filter' options don't seem to work as the former just expands properties and the latter only feeds me one line at a time.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used a custom FilterReader to solve this problem:

```
class OozieDslFilter extends FilterReader {
  OozieDslFilter(Reader input) {
    super(new StringReader(new OozieDslParser().parse(input.text)))
  }
}

task build(type: Zip) {
  with {
    archiveName = "${project.name}-${project.version}.${extension}"
    destinationDir = buildDir
  }

  from('workflow/resources')

  from('workflow/dsl') {
    rename { it - ~/\.[^\.]+$/ + '.xml' }
    filter(OozieDslFilter)
  }
}
```